# How does one tell whether a process is in kernel or user space?

Tags: process, kernel, daemon, space

Some processes, and in particular some daemons, can run in either kernel space or user space (sort of like how a user can run in normal or superuser mode). Is there a simple way to find out which it is for any given process (daemon)?

Comment: I really doubt it. You can have HTTP server in kernel space, but it definitely will not be same server as running in user space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically (in monolithic kernels, anyway), processes can run in both user space and kernel space, depending on what they're doing. The user code will run in user space until it requires kernel services, i.e. a kernel system call. The program will then cause a trap which switches the CPU to protected mode where the kernel code executes the system call (e.g. to read or write a file). Once that is complete, the kernel switches back to user mode and the user application continues running. At all times it is the user process that's running; it's just running user code or kernel code, as appropriate.

EDIT

At least on Linux, I don't think there's any way to tell if a kernel-only process will ever drop to user space; the kernel is allowed to do anything it wants, after all. But, you can use some heuristics to make an educated guess. For example, pmap will tell you what user-space memory is mapped in for the process; no memory is pretty strong evidence (perhaps incontrovertible) that it's a kernel task. In the same way, if the VSZ field in 'ps l' is 0, it means the task has no user-space memory allocated. If you're just interested in whether the task is in the kernel at this moment in time, the WCHAN field in 'ps l' will give you a hint; if it's something other than -, it's in the kernel, if it's -, then it's likely in user space, but I'm not sure if it could also mean that it's just been preempted while in kernel space.

Comment: Most daemons run in user space and switch to kernel space while running kernel code, just like applications.  There are, however, daemons specifically designed to run wholly in kernel space (a random example is kHTTPd, http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/khttpd/khttpd.html).  Clearly the pid or owner, by itself, is not enough to tell whether a process is in user or kernel space.  The question remains: how can the user (or any third party process) tell whether a given process (daemon, thread) is in kernel space or not?  Obviously one must dismiss any kernel calls made by such process.

Comment: Maybe a better question is: how does one tell whether a block of in-memory code is in user or kernel space?

Comment: The ps command has process flag 4 "used super-user privileges" (e.g. 'ps -p pid -o f' where pid is the process ID of interest); when this returns 4 (or 5 because of the other process flag of value 1), does it mean the process has at some point in its past run in kernel space?  This is not quite what I'm looking for, but it would be a start.

Comment: Here's another solution element: kernel threads don't need user-space memory page directories, so they store the NULL-pointer value in the ‘mm’ field of their ‘task_struct’ process descriptor.  The question then becomes: how does one ask the kernel about a process's task_struct.mm value?

Comment: I see now (linux/sched.h) that the two ps process flags are indeed taken from task_struct->flags (specifically PF_FORKNOEXEC 0x00000040 'forked but didn't exec', PF_SUPERPRIV 0x00000100 'used super-user privileges'). This same set of flags includes PF_KTHREAD 0x00200000 'I am a kernel thread'. It's a shame ps doesn't report this latter flag.

Comment: In some ways it would be easier to use /proc/<pid>/stat directly (that's what ps does, according to its code).  The process's stat file starts with "%c %d %d %d %d %d %lu", the seventh item ("%lu") being task_struct.flags.  Once one has that, check for PF_KTHREAD and one is done.

Comment: You could always write the functionality into ps yourself, it should be relatively easy. You could even submit it and see if the maintainers accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There are architecture specific registers which can tell which mode you are in:-

a) You can use hw/sw debuggers to check the value of that registers while debugging
e;g: CPSR for arm & CS for x86

The lower two-bits of the code segment descriptor will determine the current privilege level that the code is executing

b) From Code, you can use macro `user_mode(regs)` which internally uses **cpsr or cs register.**

**user_mode(regs) determines whether a register set came from user mode.**

e.g: in arm,  **cpsr** is used

```
#define user_mode(regs) \
    (((regs)->ARM_cpsr & 0xf) == 0)
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/arch/arm/include/asm/ptrace.h#L20

e.g:- in x86, **cs** is used

```
static inline int user_mode(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
    return ((regs->cs & SEGMENT_RPL_MASK) | (regs->flags & X86_VM_MASK)) >= USER_RPL;
#else
    return !!(regs->cs & 3);
#endif
}
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h#L106

for all other architecture, check below link

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/ident/user_mode